# textfield click vs drag

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a text field which can be clicked to edit, and dragged along the y-axis using a `UIPanGesture`.

When the user clicks the text field, I want to set the `textAlignement` to.left & when the user drags the text field around, I want to keep the text center aligned.

I initialise in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
let dragText = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(userDragged))
    textOverlay.addGestureRecognizer(dragText)

textOverlay.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
```

Callback methods:

```
func textClicked() {
    //let actLocation = textOverlay.frame.origin.y
    textOverlay.frame.origin.y = self.finalKBH
    self.textOverlay.textAlignment = .left
    print("Text clicked")
}

func userDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let loc = gesture.location(in: self.view)
    self.textOverlay.frame.origin.y = loc.y
    self.textOverlay.textAlignment = .center
    print("Text dragged")
}
```

The problem I'm having, is differentiating between an actual 'click-to-edit' and drag gesture.

While dragging the text field, the `textClicked` function is also called and the text is aligned to the left.

Is there a way I can differentiate between these two actions?

I've attempted to change the `textClicked` targer to `UIControlEvents.touchUpInside` but then my function isn't being registered in the console.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For detecting when the textfield enters editing mode, implement the `textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)` method of `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ...

    textField.delegate = self
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    print("Text clicked")
}
```

Comment: This is a proper use of textField, i'm not sure about the overlay though..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, long press if you have to use an overlay for some reason?

```
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressed:")
textOverlay.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
```